# Delete a excel tab through .bat

Tags: batch-file

I need to delete only 3 certain tabs in an excel. There any batch command for that. I can't find any solution on google.

I tried below but doesn't work-

@echo off
@del /s /q /f "C:\Excel.xlsm|||Sheet1"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete a sheet in a book directly with a batch file.

You can use a batch file to open a new workbook and then use a Macro to delete the sheet(s) in the other book.

[Delete sheet](https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/worksheet/m/delete/)

> Sub Delete_Sheet()
> Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
> ‘Or
> Sheet2.Delete End Sub